# remove Anaconda environment with no name?

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, conda, environment, interpreter

I was trying to create an Anaconda environment from Pycharm, but while I was experimenting different paths, one of the environments was created with no name. like the following:

```
base                  *  /Applications/anaconda3
snowflaks                /Users/usr/.conda/envs/snowflaks
                         /Users/usr/anaconda3/envs/snowflaks
```

I wanted to delete the environment with an empty name but could not figure out a way. I tried using "\ " to make the name empty but it didn't work. Also, there is no envs folder inside anaconda3 (which is probably why this happened?), so I can't just delete it as well.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 75):

I was able to solve a similar situation by removing it using the prefix rather than the name.

I.E. `conda env remove -p /Users/usr/anaconda3/envs/snowflaks`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Wasted so much time in finding out why isn't it removing with name

Comment: Thank you for this, I would have spent an hour struggling with this if not for your answer.